# After login success how to hide popup

Tags: angular

If login success, i want to close my popup automatically. What i wrote the code is shown in below. But this is not working. Can anyone please help.

> My html

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" >
        <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username">
        <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="password">
        <input type="button" id="btn-login" class="btn btn-success" (click)="funlogin()">Login  </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

> My ts

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
funlogin(){
///If(login==true){
$("#myModal").dialog("close")
}else{
alert(login failed)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a directive for reaching that behavior?

Jquery is totally unnecessary here. You can use your angular component for managing the modal and show it if it could be needed or hide it if it's not. Besides, managing this behavior from the parent component/view you are avoiding elements unnecessaries in the DOM

```js
public isLoggedIn = false;


funlogin(){
  this.isLoggedIn = true
}
```

```html
<modal *ngIf="!isLoggedIn">

</modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use modal('hide') method:

```
funlogin(){
    if(login==true){
       $("#myModal").modal('hide');
    }else{
      alert(login failed)
    }
}
```

Comment: It says ----->jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__(...).modal is not a function. I already imported this------->import * as $ from 'jquery'

Comment: Did you include bootstrap? I thought you need it

Comment: Yes, I included both jquery and bootstrap also.

Answer (score 0):

you can also build popup without using jquery. You can try angular bootstrap.

> @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
>
> npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --save

**sample.module.ts**

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
 declarations: [],
 imports: [NgbModule]
 })

 export class SampleModule { }
```

**sample.component.ts**

```
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

constructor(private modalService: NgbModal){}

loginAction() {
  if(login.status == 'success') {
     this.modalService.dismissAll();
  }
}
```

**sample.component.html**

```
<ng-template #loginModal let-modal >
  <span class="modalClose" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')"></span>
  <div class="modal-body" style="text-align:center">
    It is login Modal
    <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username">
    <input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
    <button (click)="loginAction()">Login</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```